# Cordova android - Keyboard covering input fields

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I know this has been asked number of times but none of the answered provide a solution.

`<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />` this isn't really a fix because I want the app to be fullscreen.

Config file options doesn't seem to do anything. I have tried:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
```

Scroll offset won't work either since there is no space to scroll.

```
$('.myinput').focus(function(e) {
    var container = $('.container'),
    scrollTo = $('.myinput');

    setTimeout((function() {
        container.animate({
            scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
        });
    }), 500);
});
```

[image: screencast]

Comment: "There's no space to scroll"?? **How comes you cannot scroll down to show the content?** This is clearly a serious CSS layout design error. First fix that, then you'll see how Android auto-scrolls to show your input fields. If this auto scroll doesn't take place, you can scroll down dynamically.

Comment: Not at all. iOS and Android automatically scrolls the input into view regardless of page height. Android has had this bug for years and still no fix. The issue comes from the fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 1):

Please install:

`cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard --save`

and then do cordova prepare to load this new plugin in your www folder.

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(e){
    window.addEventListener('native.keyboardshow', function () {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
        });
});
```

or you can try this javascript function

```
<script>
      setInterval(function(){
      if( document.body.className.match('keyboard-open') ) {
      document.getElementById("messagearea").style.marginBottom="100px";
      }
                  else{
                     document.getElementById("messagearea").style.marginBottom="0px";
                  }

                  }, 1000);

  </script>
```

Comment: None of the events of this plugin triggers unfortunately.